# Spark/Scala - Using keyBy with RDD of List[(Int, Double)]

Tags: list, scala, join, apache-spark, rdd

I'm facing a problem that I'm not sure how to approach in an elegant way. I have 2 RDD's that I need to join:

```
First - RDD[(Int, Double)]
Second - RDD[MyObject, List[(Int, Double)])
```

I need to join these 2 RDD's using `Int` as keys. With the first RDD it is clear - I can define `keyBy` using the `Int` but how can I define the `keyBy` in the second RDD? My resulted RDD has to have the following structure
`RDD[MyObject, Int, Double]` where the `Double` is the result of multiplication of the 2 `Double` above after they were joined by the `Int key`. 
I understand that I can solve this by having 2 nested loops am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use `flatMap`:

```
val first: RDD[(Int, Double)] = // ...
val second: RDD[T, List[(Int, Double)]) = // ...

val flattened: RDD[(Int, (T, Double))] = second.flatMap { case (t, list) => 
  list.map { case (i, d) => (i, (t, d)) } 
}

val joined: RDD[(Int, (Double, (T, Double)))] = first.join(flattened)
val multiplied: RDD[(T, Int, Double)] = joined.map { case (i, (d1, (t, d2))) => 
  (t, i, d1 * d2)
}
```